# Graphics on Android: path with smooth curves?

Tags: android

I want to draw a chart for a function y=x^2 as follows:

[image]

but the curve is not smooth as it is a set of connected lines.

how can I make the curve smoother ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `Path.quadTo` with only one `Path`. If you are already doing this then I suggest increasing the number of points on the graph.

Move to the beginning of the `Path`:

```
Path.moveTo(x, y)
```

in the middle:

```
Path.quadTo(lastX, lastY, (x + lastX)/2, (y + lastY)/2)
```

and at the end:

```
Path.lineTo(x, y)
```

Comment: I'm using Path.lineTo(), does increasing the points solve the problem ?

Comment: Path.quadTo() should be enough and should look significantly better than lineTo() when it comes to curves.

Comment: It's the same, maybe if I increased the points it will get better

Comment: Don't do that yet. There should be a *signficant* difference. Are you sure you are using it properly? Wait let me write something up.

Comment: Yes but it will effect performance, try using the updated answer -  it will create the same effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your method of plotting and it worked great, no need to add extra points.

Comment: Compare to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227841/901597 which employs lineTo in the first segment.